# What is the difference between a static class and a namespace? (in C#)

Tags: c#

The only difference I see is the fact that you can't use the "using staticClass" declaration.

Therefore, I'm wondering:

1. Is there a real difference between a static class and a namespace?
2. Is there a possibility to avoid having to rewrite the class name every time a member function is called? I'm thinking about something analogous to "using staticClass".

Comment: Rewriting the class name every time is actually, in my opinion, a good thing. And you don't really have to *type* the name every time - typically in Visual Studio, you'll type the first letter and then the dot, and the class is still selected.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Or, as the Python people say: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, a `static` class is technically a type. It can have members (fields, methods, events). A namespace can only hold types (and it's not considered a "type" by itself; `typeof(System)` is a compile-time error).

There's no direct equivalent to adding a `using` directive for a namespace for a static class. You can, however, declare aliases:

```
using ShortName = ReallyReallyLongStaticClassName;
```

and use

```
ShortName.Member
```

when referring its members.

Additionally, you can use static classes to declare extension methods on other types and use them directly without referring to the class name explicitly:

```
public static class IntExtensions {
   public static int Square(this int i) { return i * i; }
}
```

and use it like:

```
int i = 2;
int iSquared = i.Square(); // note that the class name is not mentioned here.
```

Of course, you'll have to add a `using` directive for the namespace containing the class to use the extension method if the class is not declared in the root or current namespace.

Comment: Btw, classes can also hold types. And I think you should mention in your last example that you need `using NamespaceContainingTheStaticClass`.

Comment: Martinho: Yes, a class can have nested types but namespaces can too. It's not a contrasting feature. The class is not declared in a namespace so you don't need to `using` it. If you declare a static class in the root namespace, its extension methods are automatically picked up (which makes it one of the reasons it's not a good idea to declare classes in root namespace).

Comment: Oh, forgot about using the root namespace. That is **so** **evil** I didn't even consider it.

Comment: Mehrdad, can you explain what you mean by "its extension methods are automatically picked up"?

Comment: I mean you don't have to explicitly add a using directive if the namespace that the static class is defined in is the root namespace or the namespace you're writing code in to use the extension methods. This is pretty intuitive behavior, of course.

Comment: Note that with C# 6 you now *can* do `using static My.Static.Class;` to be able to use all members and types declared within as top level members.

Answer (score 7):

Static class is still a class. It can contain methods, properties, etc. Namespace is just a namespace. It's just a helper to distinguish between class declarations with the same name.

Function can't live in a namespace alone, it belongs to a class.

Extensions is probably what you are looking for, if you need a static function without mentioning the name of the class.

```
public static class MathExtensions
{
 public static int Square(this int x)
 {
  return x * x;
 }
}
//...
// var hundredSquare = 100.Square();
```

Answer (score 6):

One other difference is that namespaces can span several assemblies, while classes cannot.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, namespaces are a language feature only; they get removed by compilation. In other words, the .NET runtime does not "see" namespaces, just class names that happen to contain dots. For example, the `String` class in the `System` namespace is seen by the .NET runtime as a class named `System.String`, but there is no concept of namespace at all.

Static classes, however, are fully understood and managed by the .NET runtime. They are fully-fledged types and you can use reflection on them.